# Passing 2 variables through django url

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I try to pass 2 variables through url config

url.py

```
url(r'^essays/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.EssayDetailView.as_view(), name='essay_view'),
```

view.py

```
class EssayDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Essay

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EssayDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['category'])

        return context
```

but if I use in template *url* tag like this

```
<a href = "{{essay.get_absolute_url}}">{{essay.title}}</a>
```

I've error **NoReverseMatch**. With 1 parameter it works right. For example url:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_view'),
```

how can i pass 2 variables to generic view? Or should I wright my own view method?

Comment: Show us your model's `get_absolute_url` function. If not overriden, that's your starting point then.

Answer (score 1):

It was mistyping in

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:essay_view', args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])
```

now works tnx